# The localization principle for the Fourier integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f,g \in L_1(\mathbb R)$. Prove that if $f$ and $g$ coincide in a neighborhood of sime point $x_0$  then the Fourier integrals of these functions either converge or diverge simultaneously to the same value.

I think we need to use here the Riemann Lemma: if $f\in L_1(\mathbb R)$ then $\lim _{A\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-iA t}dt=0$. Since $f=g$ in this neighborhood, then we can consider their difference, i.e $f-g=0$ and thus the Fourier transform $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(f(t)-g(t))e^{-iA t}dt=0$. But I do not know what to do next.

Comment: Could you clarify, what you mean by "the Fourier integrals of these functions either converge or diverge simultaneously to the same value"? 
I mean, $f,g$ are $L^1$ functions, so by the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma, both $\hat{f},\hat{g}$ vanish at infinity. But this has nothing to do with both functions coinciding somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $h$ is a function in $L^1$ that is differentiable at a point $x$. Then
$$
            \lim_{R\uparrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}e^{isx}\hat{h}(s)ds = h(x).
$$
Under your hypotheses, the above applied to $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ shows that the inverse Fourier integrals of $\hat{f},\hat{g}$ either converge to the same values at $x$, or they both diverge at $x$.